# Как реализовать Spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

У меня есть таблица, в ней username, password. Подскажите, как мне реализовать *Spring security* для входа. Мне не нужны полномочия, просто войти или нет.

Answer (score 1):

вот тут очень хорошо все написано [https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/)

Если в двух словах Вам нужны классы:
1.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 это главный класс, который дает разрешения на просмотр информации и сюда стекается вся информация с Вашего сайта.
```

2. UserDetailsImpl здесь происходит поиск юзера по имени

   ```
   @Service
   public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService {
       @Autowired
       private UserRepository userRepository;
       @Override
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String useName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

           UsersModel one = userRepository.findOne(useName);

           return one;
       }
   }
   ```
3. MyPasswordEncoder если юзер найден идет поиск по паролю

   ```
   @Service
   public class MyPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

       @Override
       public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
           return charSequence.toString();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {

           return s.equals(charSequence.toString());

       }
   }
   ```

п. 2 и 3 практически всегда имеют такой вид, по дебагеру, при залогинивании меня не закидывает в п.1

Есть еще 4 класс

4. Если вы используете к примеру Thymeleaf он учит его читать

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

}
```

Но это я выдернул со своего проекта, под Ваш надеюсь он подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Подобная конфигурация описана довольно подробно в документации
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-jdbc
там есть и примеры кода и т.д.

А реализация UserDetailsService для получения данных о юзере совсем не обязательна.